# Sharing memory with a non-contiguous subset of a matrix in Armadillo/C++

Tags: c++, armadillo

Hi is the following possible and if so, any tips on how to do it?

This is a dummy version of what I would like to achieve: Define three matrices A, B, and C with A_xy standard normally distributed and B_xy = A_xy for A_xy > 0 and 0 otherwise. Likewise  C_xy = A_xy for A_xy <= 0 and 0 otherwise.

To avoid a copy operation, I'd like to construct B and C such that the non-zero elements share memory with A. Is that even possible?! If I construct B and C in sparse matrix format then I don't need to worry about the additional zeros which would not share memory, but this might end up slower, depending on the sparsity of B and C...

In the following B and C obviously don't share memory with A, but should give an idea of what I want to do:

```
arma_rng::set_seed(1);
mat A;
A.randn(4,4);
uvec indB = find(A > 0);
uvec indC = find(A <= 0);

// Copy construction
mat B, C;
B.zeros(4,4);
B.elem(indB) = A.elem(indB);
C.zeros(4,4);
C.elem(indC) = A.elem(indC);

A.print("A");
B.print("B");
C.print("C");
```

Which gives as output:

```
A
  -0.3868  -0.7951   0.1175  -1.5241
  -0.0394  -0.0546  -0.8588  -0.4954
   0.6868   1.9379  -0.6483   0.9138
  -0.2489   1.0010   0.6746  -0.6272
B
        0        0   0.1175        0
        0        0        0        0
   0.6868   1.9379        0   0.9138
        0   1.0010   0.6746        0
C
  -0.3868  -0.7951        0  -1.5241
  -0.0394  -0.0546  -0.8588  -0.4954
        0        0  -0.6483        0
  -0.2489        0        0  -0.6272
```

I have in mind something like:

```
// Auxiliary memory construction
mat B2(vec (A.elem(indB)).memptr(), A.n_rows, A.n_cols, false, true);
B2.print("B2");
```

Which gives

```
B2
   6.8682e-01   6.7457e-01  4.6573e-310  4.6573e-310
   1.9379e+00   9.1377e-01  6.9257e-310  6.9257e-310
   1.0010e+00  4.6573e-310  4.6573e-310  4.6573e-310
   1.1752e-01  6.9257e-310  6.9257e-310  6.9257e-310
```

Not what I want but hopefully you get the idea!

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible in Armadillo.  But it is possible in Eigen.  Armadillo submatrix views generally operate by copy, Eigen submatrix views are pointers to the original object. Big difference there.  You can also do this yourself by mapping a pointer array using std::vector, but then you'd better know what you're doing and you're no longer taking advantage of contiguous memory (which could be a huge performance let-down).

Comment: When I have a situation like this I generally tend to copy to B or C, run my calculations, and then map results back to A. That way I get the performance benefit of contiguous memory lookup in B and C while running the operations, and mapping it back to A is just a straightforward copy to memory already allocated.

Comment: @zdebruine Looking at the Armadillo source code, the submatrix views reference the original object where possible.

Comment: @hbrekere I stand corrected! Still, doing lots of computation on non-contiguous submatrix references could well be slower than a doing the same on a copy followed by updating the original object.